# 20-40 ms performance difference during peak traffic on amazon RDS

Tags: mysql

I am noticing during peak traffic the average mysql response time is 20-40 ms longer consistently as reported by new relic. I have tried turning on query cache and making the innodb buffer pool larger with no luck. The total response time is still around 125ms; but am concerned that I am missing a setting that could help.

I don't recall having this issue with Rackspace with the same set of data and traffic. Could it just come down to the fact there is just a bit more load on the database and is acceptable?

I have an 8GB Amazon RDS instance with a 4gb buffer pool and I turned on the query cache with a 75% hit rate which didn't move the needle.

Could the issue be related to being in a shared environment at all? My CPU usage is under 20% (usually a lot less).

here are my settings:
https://gist.github.com/blasto333/9e82b6261681303f7369c3a2652e03f2

I am just looking for ideas to try. My two ideas were making the buffer pool larger was 3gb now 4gb; and turning the query cache on (As I had with rackspace). So far those didn't move the needle.

Answer (score 0):

20-40ms is about a thousand miles of latency.  Where are the client and server, relative to each other?  Is Amazon moving the Server around?  Or the Client?

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is set reasonably by Amazon (I think).  Do *not* raise it without raising the amount of RAM?  There is no benefit in making the buffer_pool much bigger than the entire dataset (data & indexes).

For an 8GB VM (which is probably only 7.5GB), 6G is about the max that is safe -- assuming that *only* MySQL is running in that VM.

Turning on the QC is usually a waste on production systems (except on Aurora).  Also, do *not* set `query_cache_size` bigger than about 50M -- else it could slow things down.

20% CPU -- percent of one core?  Of all cores?  20% of all cores seems high.  What is your slowest query?  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: The query cache actually helped now the difference between peak and off peak is 5-10ms. The time I was referring to is MySQL response time as reported by newrelic for server to process all sql statements.